# Using pathlib.Path on MacOS to escape Windows paths correctly

Tags: python, macos, path

I am in the process of scanning through a network drive while on MacOS which contains multiple directories which are full copies of hard drives that began as Windows volumes.

Example:

```
file_path = pathlib.Path("/Volumes/fotos/hd2/Old 160gig HD/Pictures/Location/Location Pictures/100MEDIA/Dalan\'s Desert")
```

If I use Python's `subprocess` to run something like `subprocess.run(["open", file_path])` I get the following error:

```
The file /Volumes/fotos/hd2/Old 160gig HD/Pictures/Location/Location Pictures/100MEDIA/Dalan\'s Desert does not exist
```

I get variable success if I comment out the apostrophes and/or spaces but it doesn't seem consistent? I also attempted this with `shell=True` but can't seem to find a solution that works 100% of the time.

What is the canonical way within Python of handling paths so that they *always* work in an MacOS context?

Comment: Try this; from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath, PurePosixPath; If you want Windows conventions, use PureWindowsPath() to convert it to a pathlib object, then pass that to Path() to convert and use it dow the line;

Answer (score 0):

We can refer the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePosixPath); The first [image](https://docs.python.org/3/_images/pathlib-inheritance.png) in the very beginning is very helpful as well;

```py
In [1]: from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath, PurePosixPath                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [2]: PureWindowsPath(Path("/Volumes/fotos/hd2/Old 160gig HD/Pictures/Location/Location Pictures/100MEDIA/Dalan\'s Desert"))                                                                                                                              
Out[2]: PureWindowsPath("/Volumes/fotos/hd2/Old 160gig HD/Pictures/Location/Location Pictures/100MEDIA/Dalan's Desert")

In [3]: PurePosixPath(Path("/Volumes/fotos/hd2/Old 160gig HD/Pictures/Location/Location Pictures/100MEDIA/Dalan\'s Desert"))                                                                                                                                
Out[3]: PurePosixPath("/Volumes/fotos/hd2/Old 160gig HD/Pictures/Location/Location Pictures/100MEDIA/Dalan's Desert")
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in the `PureWindowsPath` nor the `PurePosixPath`?